# Unicode Error while getting frame from .h5 file in python

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, hdf5, hdfstore

I'm trying to read a .h5 file using pandas.HDFStore

with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
```

and it works, the problem happen when trying this line of code

```
df1 = store['df1']
```

and it returns this error:

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2108: ordinal not in range(128)"

I tried the solution in this [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11234) but it didn't work also.

So please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

There are different encoding and its usually difficult to find which one.
try encoding= 'ISO-8859-1'